# Spring and XSLT, character encoding

Tags: java, xml, spring

I have problem with proper charset encoding part of HTML view. XSL file in JSP files generates .html.
Values from database are encoded correct, but static headers of table contain wrong characters.

For example, there are headers named: 
Imię, Nazwisko, Hasło, Płeć,
but it generates: 
ImiÄ™, Nazwisko, HasÅ‚o, PÅ‚eÄ‡

My forHomeHtml.xml template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="xhtml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/employees">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Imię</th>
            <th>Nazwisko</th>
            <th>Hasło</th>
            <th>Płeć</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="./employee">
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="name/text()" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="surname/text()" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="password/text()" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="gender/text()" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
```

JSP site:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="x" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<c:import var="inputDocument"
url="http://localhost:8080/xyz/home.xml" />
<c:import var="stylesheet" url="/WEB-INF/xsl/forHomeHtml.xsl" />

<x:transform xml="${inputDocument}" xslt="${stylesheet}">
</x:transform>
```

I use Tiles, so the encoding is declared in main template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<html>
<head>
<title><tiles:getAsString name="title" /></title>
...
```

I will add that I have encoding filter in web.xml

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>encoding</param-name>
    <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Character encoding of files (JSP, XSL, XML, etc.) is setted to UTF-8.
Character encoding of the browser is setted to UTF-8.

Does anybody know the reason of that problem?

---

**Update**: It is strange, but the source of site contains following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-    transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Strona główna</title>
<style type="text/css">
.table-list {
border: 1px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
...
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table width="100%" border="0">
<tr style="background-color: #EEEEEE;">
<td><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ul class="navigation_menu">
<li><a href="./home.htm">Strona główna</a></li>
<li><a href="./rejestracja.htm">Rejestracja</a></li>
<li><a href="./historia-wypozyczen-samochodu.htm">Historia samochodu</a></li>
<li><a href="./dodawanie-zamowienia.htm">Dodawanie zamówienia</a></li>
</ul>

<div style="text-align: center;">
Liczba obsłużonych dzisiaj zamówień:
0
</div></td></tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top" align="left">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE table PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-    transitional.dtd">
<table xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<tr>
<th />
<th>ImiÄ&#153;</th>
<th>Nazwisko</th>
<th>HasÅ&#130;o</th>
<th>PÅ&#130;eÄ&#135;</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td />
<td>Zenon</td>
<td>Kowalski</td>
<td>zHasło</td>
<td>Mężczyzna</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td /></tr>
....
<tr style="background-color: #EEEEEE;">
<td><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<div style="text-align: center;"></div></td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

There's no content-type header!

Should I change my Tiles template?

Btw, @Alejandro, @Jim Garrison - thanks for tips.

Comment: What you describe is UTF-8 being interpreted as if it were ISO-8859-1 (or some other single-byte character set).  How do you KNOW the browser is set to interpret the data stream as UTF-8, and that the data stream declares itself to be UTF-8?  Can you post a screen shot showing both correct and incorrect UTF-8 characters?

Comment: Even better, capture the traffic going to the browser and examine the headers to verify that the stream is indeed tagged as UTF-8.  We know it's UTF-8, but we don't know if it's identified as UTF-8 by the headers.

Comment: @bontade: I agree with @Jim Garrison. This looks like a browser issue. You need to output a proper (X)HTML document with `meta` element with proper encoding.

Comment: `Imię, Nazwisko, Hasło, Płeć` saved as UTF-8 results in same byte stream as `ImiÄ™, Nazwisko, HasÅ‚o, PÅ‚eÄ‡` saved as windows-1252. So wrong characters are shown because browser guesses the charset wrong or the charset is not explicitly mentioned in the document (in a `<META>` element). As a small nitpick: there is no output method `xhtml` in XSLT 1.0

Comment: more nitpicks ;) Your XSLT produces unnecessary XML declarations and doctype definitions in the middle of the document.

Comment: I putted `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />` in Tiles template, but output is the same :(

Comment: Are you answering your own question, or adding to it?

Comment: Those extra XML declarations might be messing with how the browser is parsing the HTML. Find out where/why you have multiple XML declarations and see if that helps. Also, for debugging - it might be easier to capture the output and make local edits and view results in the browser until you fix it, then update the transform to achieve desired results.

Comment: When I run your XSLT, I don't get those characters as entities.  I don't think your issue is with the XSLT, but in what is emitting the output. You should see `Imię`, not `ImiÄ&#153;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as if the JSTL is either not reading or outputting UTF-8 data correctly.  I found several reports of issues with UTF-8 data and JSTL transforms, but not a lot of solutions.

**I did find [this page describing a similar problem with JSTL and UTF-8 support](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aebBshacwKgIJ%3awever.org/java/space/java/UTF-8%2Bbug%2Bin%2BJSTL%27s%2Bxml%2Btransform%2Btag+jstl+utf-8+transform&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a&source=www.google.com). The solution was to switch transformers and use Saxon.**