# Spring - web pages using XSLT

Tags: spring, xslt, saxon, xalan

I'm new in XSLT and I would know what is the best solution to integrate XSLT into Spring web application. I found quick example [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JSP/JSPXMLandXSLTtransform.htm), but all in all I had troubles with proper character encoding and switching to Saxon processor (I refer to my former questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950918/spring-and-xslt-character-encoding) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118042/spring-xslt-switching-from-xalan-to-saxon)). In book: 'Spring in Action' is described solution by extending AbstractXsltView. Is better way than AbstractXsltView which would let me choose Saxon processor? Is better way than execute transformation from .jsp files?

Answer (score 1):

There's an old [IBM DeveloperWorks JSTL primer](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jstl0520/) on doing transformations through JSP using the `<x:transform>` tag of JSTL. This would be a much simpler approach, but may not allow Saxon.