# JSON: How to log a JSON object value from a vxml?

Tags: json, vxml

My aim is to log a JSON object value fethed from a jsp file from the vxml. Is there any way to do that. I see that there is a function called JSON.stringify but thats giving me nothing as a log.
Below is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<vxml version="2.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/vxml">

        <var name="userId" expr="1" />
        <!--form id="get_location"-->
                        <data name="userData" method="get" src="http://localhost:5000/userLocation.jsp" nameList="userId" />

                <property name="inputmodes" value="dtmf"/>
                <menu id="menuZero">
                <choice dtmf="1" next="#choice1"/>
                 <choice dtmf="2" next="#choice2"/>

                 </menu>
        <!--/form-->
<form id="choice1">
        <block>
                <if cond="userData.HttpResponse.do_queryResponse[&apos;return&apos;].errorMsg.result_code != &apos;0&apos;">
                                                <goto next="welcome.vxml"/>
                                                                                 <else/>
                                                                                                                  <goto next="welcome.vxml"/>
                                                                                                                                                   </if>
  </block>
  </form>
  <form id="choice2">
          <block>
 <log expr="JSON.stringify(userData.HttpResponse)"/>
          </block>

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               </form>
</vxml>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring - web pages using XSLT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133375/spring-web-pages-using-xslt)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, VoiceXML is not supported "JSON.stringify".
Try to get "[json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)" and add code.

```
<script src="json2.js" />
```

For example,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<vxml
    version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/vxml"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >

    <script src="json2.js" />

    <var name="messageObject" expr="{keyA:'valueA',keyB:'valueB',keyC:'valueC'}" />

    <form>
        <block><prompt>Write Log!</prompt></block>
        <block><log expr="JSON.stringify(messageObject)"/></block>
    </form>

</vxml>
```

I tested this code on "Voxeo Prophecy 13".

Comment: Should i include any other file aprt from json2.js because im getting this error "Assignment to undeclared variable JSON (-#162) "

Comment: I further checked your code and found few problem. 1 - data element is not supported VoiceXML 2.0. It is supported VoiceXML 2.1 later. 2 - data element is not supported JSON. It can to use XML only. 3 - [DOM's Docment object](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/ecma-script-binding.html) have not "HttpResponse".

Answer (score 0):

I tried json2.js as described above and I had the same issue, 'assignment to undeclared variable JSON'. To fix this, I just declared in the same file (json2.js):

```
var JSON;
```

Then it worked properly. In the vxml:

```
<script><![CDATA[
     prueba = new Object();
     prueba.pepito = 1234;
     prueba.OtraPrueba = "lalalapepe";
]]></script>
     <log label="IVB_HISTORY">
         <value expr="JSON.stringify(prueba)"/>
     </log>
```

It gets logged as followed:

```
{"pepito":1234,"OtraPrueba":"lalalapepe"}
```

I'm using Convergy's InVision Studio